# Validating a String and calling an activity as per the result

Tags: android

I wanted to call a different activity if my String value(from) is empty and vice verse:

```
    String[] from = new String[] { "name" };

    if (from.length >= 1)

    {
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.countryTextView111};
        conAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(CountryList.this, R.layout.countrylist, null, from, to);
        setListAdapter(conAdapter); // set adapter

    }   
    else 

    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EmailSettings.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

For some reason my Condition isn't working so need an Expert view.

Thanks,

Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] from = new String[] { "name" };

for(int i=0;i<from.length;i++)
   {
      if(from[i]>="conditon")
       {
         //try code this
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thats it that was the correct answer :) thank you so much mate and i am now going to mark this Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the **length** of the **array**, and it contains one entry so its length is **1**
If you want to check the first entry's length then

```
String[] from = new String[] { "name" };

if (from[0].length >= 1)

{
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.countryTextView111};
    conAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(CountryList.this, R.layout.emailsettings, null, from, to);
    setListAdapter(conAdapter); // set adapter

}   
else 

{

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EmailSettings.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: It will only be carrying one value so how to check in this way?

Comment: i do not understand, if it will always contains one entry, then why the if else

Comment: Right now DB is empty so the String is also not carrying any value but for some strange reason its not jumping to "else" and staying at the first part.

Comment: String[] from = new String[] { "name" }; here you are putting (name) into the string array so it's length is 1, so it wont enter in else

Comment: Yes thats true but "name" is mapped to a DB value. How can i check if this string is not containing any result coming from DB?

Comment: if i understand well, you need to get the values stored in the db and compare them with your array

Comment: if (from.length >= 1) remove = sign in this condition

Comment: Again no value coming from DB as its empty but still its not jumping to second condition.

Comment: then put an empty array String[] from = new String[] {  };